# git work tree not a repository

Tags: git, githooks

I'm trying to set up a remote repo for a live web server. The way I was taught to set this up was to make a post-receive file in the hooks dir like this:

```
#!/bin/sh
git --work-tree=/var/www/domain.com --git-dir=/var/repo/site.git checkout -f
```

so that the live web folder doesn't have the git folders in it.

However, if I add files to the work tree, I can't add those to my git repo. It says: fatal: Not a git repository (or any parent up to mount parent ).

I realize this may not be a good idea to do in the first place, but I like the fact that my hosting service has one click install options, which make setting up WordPress, for example, easy.

Is there any way to add these files into the git?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Any command using the options `--work-tree`and `--git-dir` (as in `--work-tree=/var/www/domain.com --git-dir=/var/repo/site.git`) would detect/add or commit those files.

For instance:

```
git --work-tree=/var/www/domain.com --git-dir=/var/repo/site.git status
```

That would detect any modification in the `/var/www/domain.com` working tree, based on the bare repo `/var/repo/site.git`.

Comment: Ah, thanks. That worked. Now I'll have to figure out how to edit the env variables so I don't have to type as much as Andrew C Suggested

Answer (score 0):

Either pass in via the command line as Von suggests, or if you are going to be doing a lot of operations in that repository set the environmental variables GIT_DIR and GIT_WORK_TREE to save yourself some typing.

Answer (score 0):

As of `git version 2.17.1`, worktree folders contain a small `.git` file which contains:

`gitdir: /path-to-parent/.git/worktrees/this-tree-name`.

Notice that, in this example, an *absolute path* is specified.  If this path is not valid for some reason (maybe you moved the folder), then you get the error:

> fatal: not a git repository

Experimentally, I determined that this can be a *relative path*, which may be less error prone.

In any case, the generic solution to this error message is to make sure that `.git`:`gitdir:` points to a valid worktree folder within the parent `.git` folder -- wherever that may reside.

I the normal case, this should be set to:

`gitdir: ../.git/worktrees/this-tree-name`

Comment: Sorry, `git version 2.17.1` happens to be what I tested with.  I don't know when this feature was introduced -- maybe it's always been there.